# facing problems in installing tensorflow

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm, installation, tensorflow.js

I am facing problem in instaling `tensorflow`, please help me. Here is the error that I get:

```
^3.1
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dell\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-windows-3.15.0.zip
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.7.0.zip
npm ERR! * Downloading libtensorflow
npm ERR! node:events:368
npm ERR!       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)
npm ERR! Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
npm ERR!   errno: -4077,
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNRESET',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'read'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-16T07_20_26_616Z-debug.log
```

Command: `npm i @tensorflow-models/coco-ssd @tensorflow/tfjs-node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try running the following command:

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
2. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
3. Then run: `npm install`

Comment: Is python required to use tensorflow?